# Extract/print Exim loaded aliases (for mailman3)

Tags: python, exim, mailman

How do you extract or print Exim's aliases that it's using, when using it through Mailman3?

Mailman uses Exim, and includes nine aliases which point to seven different wrapped scripts:
https://docs.mailman3.org/projects/mailman/en/latest/src/mailman/runners/docs/OVERVIEW.html

I see this showing python commands, but it's using Postfix, while I'm using Exim, and I'm unclear what I'd need to change to make it work:
https://docs.mailman3.org/projects/mailman/en/latest/src/mailman/commands/docs/aliases.html

I wrote up this, and getting stuck with `postfix_domains`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os, tempfile
from mailman.testing.documentation import cli
output_directory = tempfile.mkdtemp()
with open(os.path.join(output_directory, 'postfix_domains')) as fp:
    print(fp.read())
```

```
mailman:/opt/mailman# python3 ./t1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mailman/./t1.py", line 5, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join(output_directory, 'postfix_domains')) as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpya2xx0tq/postfix_domains'
mailman:/opt/mailman#
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no need to generate aliases in the case of using Exim as MTA.

As noted [here](https://docs.mailman3.org/projects/mailman/en/latest/src/mailman/docs/mta.html#exim):

> The configuration presented below is mostly boilerplate that allows
> Exim to automatically discover your list addresses, and route both
> posts and administrative messages to the right Mailman services. For
> this reason, the mailman.mta.exim4 module ends up with all methods
> being no-ops.

The Exim configuration file listed below in the docs is sufficient to work fine with new mailing lists created in the server. However, you need to add new domains to the configuration explicitly, e.g.

```
domainlist mm_domains=list.example.net:list2.example.com
```

(In the case of using Postfix everything will be updated automatically.)

Comment: How would you trigger it on any domain hosted by exim? such that any domain could host an email list?